# Проблема с синхронизацией TextBox-а и TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

Класс для формирования Items в TreeView

```
public class NodeNap
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int IDp { get; set; }
    public string Nap { get; set; }     

    private ObservableCollection<NodeNap> node;
    public ObservableCollection<NodeNap> Node
    {
        get
        {
            if (node == null) node = new ObservableCollection<NodeNap>();
            return node;
        }
    }

    public NodeNap(int ID, int IDp, string Nap)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.IDp = IDp;
        this.Nap = Nap;
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в TreeView не отображается синхронный вывод текста, который я ввожу в TextBox, и все отлично, когда текст вводится в ComboBox. Как решить эту проблему?

```
    NodeNap root;
    NodeNap child;
    bool rootNode; //Флаг, указывающий, создан корневой(True) узел, или нет(False)
    bool childNode;// -------------------------дочерний(True) узел, или нет(False)
    private ObservableCollection<NodeNap> node = new ObservableCollection<NodeNap>();
    public ObservableCollection<NodeNap> Node { get; set; }

    private void ComboBoxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!rootNode)
        {
            root = new NodeNap(++ID, 0, ((ComboBox)sender).Text);

            Binding bin1 = new Binding
            {
                Source = root,
                Path = new PropertyPath("Nap"),
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
            };
            сomboBox1.SetBinding(ComboBox.TextProperty, bin1);
            Node.Add(root);
            rootNode = true;
        }
    }

    private void TextBoxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!childNode && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(сomboBox1.Text))
        {
            child = new NodeNap(ID + 1, ID, ((TextBox)sender).Text);
            Binding bin2 = new Binding
            {
                Source = child,
                Path = new PropertyPath("Nap"),
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
            };
            textBox1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bin2);
            root.Node.Add(child);
            childNode = true;
        }
    }
```

Лишний код, который открывает-закрывает узлы или изменяет цвет узлов дерева убран.

Comment: @rdorn, RoutedEventArgs только у routed-событий, приведенные в вопросе таковыми, конечно же, не являются (кто может обработать изменения текста в текстбоксе кроме него самого?). Но вообще подход автора очень странный. В нормальном WPF-приложении эти обработчики событий вообще не нужны. Достаточно реализовать INPC и написать правильную привязку в разметке. В чем нужна создавать Binding каждый раз? Проще уж тогда сразу менять целевое поле. А правильнее написать Binding один раз в разметке и он будет обновлять целевое поле сам.

Comment: @АндрейNOP. Combo/TexBox находятся в модальном окне. Их данные служат ObservableCollection<NodeNap> для формирования Items, родительского и дочернего, в TreeView. Ввод первого символа в ComboBox(TextChanged) - создается объект NodeNap и привязывается к ComboBox(для синхронного вывода текста в TreeView), далее объект NodeNap передается в ObservableCollection<NodeNap> - создается родительский Item. IsExpanded = true; Флаг rootNode = true; Больше код в ComboBoxTextChanged не выполняется.

Comment: @АндрейNOP. Примерно тоже самое в TextBoxTextChanged, с той разницей, что привязка нового объекта NodeNap осущ. к TexBox-у и созданный Item дочерний. Только ComboBox отрабатывает, а TexBox - только первый символ, а остальной текст появляется после закрытия модального окна.

Comment: Может надо в привязке установить `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP. Пробовал - результат тот же.